# How to extract data from POP3 email?

Tags: php, email, pop3

I receive email from POP3 server with PHP. I have a raw string containing headers and body. How can I get headers and body parsed in form of a class or array?

Example of what I have:

```
Return-path: Envelope-to: x@x.de Delivery-date:
Wed, 06 Feb 2013 09:35:37 +0100 Received: from mail by
host6.toxpress.com with spam-scanned (Exim 4.80.1) (envelope-from ) id
1U30Tc-0003sH-LQ for x@x.de; Wed, 06 Feb 2013
09:35:36 +0100 X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.2 (2011-06-06)
on host6.toxpress.com X-Spam-Level: X-Spam-Status: No, score=-1.9
required=5.0 tests=BAYES_00,FREEMAIL_FROM,
RCVD_IN_DNSWL_NONE,TVD_SPACE_RATIO autolearn=ham version=3.3.2
Received: from moh3-ve2.go2.pl ([193.17.41.86] helo=moh3-ve1.go2.pl)
by host6.toxpress.com with esmtp (Exim 4.80.1) (envelope-from ) id
1U30Tc-0003rk-2b for x@x.de; Wed, 06 Feb 2013
09:35:32 +0100 Received: from moh3-ve1.go2.pl (unknown [10.0.0.157])
by moh3-ve1.go2.pl (Postfix) with ESMTP id BC734AF611B for ; Wed, 6
Feb 2013 09:34:31 +0100 (CET) Received: from unknown (unknown
[10.0.0.108]) by moh3-ve1.go2.pl (Postfix) with SMTP for ; Wed, 6 Feb
2013 09:34:31 +0100 (CET) Received: from
43.dynamic.chello.pl [89.69.42.127] by poczta.o2.pl with
ESMTP id jtIGfv; Wed, 06 Feb 2013 09:34:31 +0100 Message-ID:
<51121593.3090008@o2.pl> Date: Wed, 06 Feb 2013 09:34:27 +0100 From:
Tomasz Reply-To: tomasz_smykrowski@o2.pl Organization: Tomasz
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:20.0) Gecko/20100101
Thunderbird/20.0a2 MIME-Version: 1.0 To: x@x.de
Subject: adaads Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1;
format=flowed Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit X-O2-Trust: 2, 64
X-O2-SPF: neutral dsadasdsaas .
```

And what i want to be able to do:

```
echo $from;
echo $replyTo;
echo $date;
echo $body;
echo $subject;
echo $charset;
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/willdurand/EmailReplyParser

Comment: @j0k It's able to get the content i suppose, but does not parse the header tags :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [MIME E-mail message parser](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3169-PHP-Decode-MIME-e-mail-messages.html) class.
According to the author's description:

> This class can be used to parse and decode MIME e-mail messages. It
>   supports decoding single RFC 2822 MIME messages or archives that
>   aggregate multiple messages in the mbox format. **The decoded message
>   data is returned as an array that describes one or more messages found
>   in a message file or data string**. The bodies of multipart messages can
>   be decoded into distinct sub-messages. The message body data can
>   decoded and saved to separate files, so the class can handle messages
>   larger than the available memory.

Comment: seems interesting, i will try this and come back

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course there is: `mailparse`

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php

Comment: I don't have mailparse installed it's shared hosting. Is there any work around?

Comment: Just `sudo pecl install mailparse && echo 'extension=mailparse.so' >> /etc/php5/conf.d/50-mailparse.ini`

Comment: unless you have no C compiler on the server... install `g++` package

Comment: It's shared hosting, so i can not install packages :(

Answer (score 1):

You could chop the email into arrays using the **bounce_driver.class**:

https://github.com/cfortune/PHP-Bounce-Handler/blob/master/bounce_driver.class.php

Comment: thx but It does not parse the from, reply to, charset and so on, so for bounce it's nice but for my case it's not so helpful

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use IMAP extension which have useful function to read IMAP & POP messages.
Open connexion using `imap_open` , then read the header using `imap_headerinfo`, it will return an array with all headers (Subject, To, ...) then use `imap_body` to get the body of the message. 
It will be easy to parse all messages without using Regex or another functions.
You can find [here](http://garrettstjohn.com/entry/reading-emails-with-php/) a simple example.

Here is a simple output of `imap_headerinfo`:

```
stdClass Object (
    [Date] => 23 Apr 2003 22:10:21 +0100
    [Subject] => Top Deals: GBP 15 Gift Certificate Offer and at Least 30% off Recommended Books
    [message_id] => <.AAA-39045660-13180,1295.1051132221@mail-ems-103.amazon.com>
    [toaddress] => xxxx@yyyy.co.uk
    [to] => Array ([0] => stdClass Object ([mailbox] => xxxx [host] => yyyy.co.uk ) )
    [fromaddress] => "Amazon.co.uk" <foryou@amazon.co.uk>
    [from] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [personal] => Amazon.co.uk [mailbox] => foryou [host] => amazon.co.uk ) )
    [reply_toaddress] => "Amazon.co.uk" <foryou@amazon.co.uk>
    [reply_to] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [personal] => Amazon.co.uk [mailbox] => foryou [host] => amazon.co.uk ) )
    [senderaddress] => "Amazon.co.uk" <foryou@amazon.co.uk>
    [sender] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [personal] => Amazon.co.uk [mailbox] => foryou [host] => amazon.co.uk ) )
    [Recent] =>
    [Unseen] =>
    [Flagged] => F
    [Answered] =>
    [Deleted] =>
    [Draft] =>
    [Msgno] => 250
    [MailDate] => 23-Apr-2003 22:22:32 +0100
    [Size] => 36375
    [udate] => 1051132952
)
```

Comment: It looks nice, but i dont have IMAP extension also :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Zend Framework's `Zend_Mail` module?

According to the manual page: 
*Zend_Mail can read mail messages from several local or remote mail storages. All of them have the same basic API to count and fetch messages and some of them implement additional interfaces for not so common features.*

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.read.html

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3(array('host'     => 'localhost',
                                         'user'     => 'test',
                                         'password' => 'test'));

echo $mail->countMessages() . " messages found\n";
foreach ($mail as $message) {
    echo "Mail from '{$message->from}': {$message->subject}\n";
}
```

Comment: I dont have ZEND installed unfortunately :(